How are these T-distillation circuits derived?
I'm trying to wrap my head around T-distillation circuits, specifically for the 15-to-1 distillation code. My question is, how does one discover these circuits from the description of the code?
There are a few that appear in the literature, for example this one from 1208.0928:

But the circuits in the literature seem to me that they appeared by "magic" (pardon the pun). How does one find these circuits?
I really like the circuit from 2101.02211 because it has a very beautiful symmetry to its structure:

How does one show that this is the correct circuit? Is there an algorithmic way to construct it from a description of the underlying code?
Another question: To prove that the circuit is indeed correct, is it enough to show that it has the same stabilizers as the code?
I really appreciated this line from the paper 2101.02211, which helpfully hints that the circuit's stabilizers can be found

by propagating the initial single-qubit stabilizers through the CNOT circuit,

which helped me verify what the stabilizer checks are for that circuit. But I still wanted to understand how they came up with the beautifully symmetric circuit in that paper.

I think there are generally two ingredients you see in state distillation circuits:

Compression. The circuit should use T gates in some complicated pattern, but do something simple. For example, a circuit that performs T gates but ends up equal to the identity operation.

Detection. If you replace a T gate with Z*T, there should be observable symptoms.


Codes with transversal T gates get detection from the fact that they are codes, and compression from the logical action (one T gate) being simpler than the physical action (many T gates).
You can also get compression from simple circuit identities, and detection from the other qubits involved in the identity. For example, if you apply a 45 degree rotation to all odd-Z Pauli products of a 5 qubit system in the $|+\rangle^{\otimes 5}$ state, it ends up back in the $|+\rangle^{\otimes 5}$ state:

By checking that some of the qubits were in fact in the $|+\rangle$ state, you can get detection. By skipping some of the final single-qubit T gates and keeping the qubit, instead of checking in, you get simple T states coming out of this more complicated sequence (compression). If skip one T gate and keep 1 output as a T state, this circuit is isomorphic to the 15-to-1 distillation circuit with distance 3. If you keep 2, its a 14-to-2 circuit with distance 2.
So one way to find distillation factories is to just try patterned combinations of gates, and see if they end up doing something simple. If they do, see if you can ablate part of the circuit to leave behind an interesting state while maintaining the ability to detect errors.
You can also generate them via triorthogonal matrices, by controlling transversal Clifford gates with a cat state, by combining existing distillation factories into larger productions, and so on.
Here is a non-trivial example of combining constructions. Consider the circuit identity above. As written, it's sort of like a 16-to-0 factory. If there is an error in any one of the 16 T gates, it will flag a problem. If you power those T gates with T states, it can be used to fully-destructively check those states. In fact it won't detect just one error; it has a surprisingly high distance (6 or 8 IIRC). Now note that the same circuit identity, modified to work in 15-to-1 mode, has 4 check qubits where the circuit ends by applying a T gate to that qubit and verifying it ended up Off. That's the circuit verifying that qubit was in a T state. Instead of verifying it by performing a T gate, we could verify it using the 16-to-0 identity. Perform four instances of the 15-to-1 factory, producing 4 T state output qubits and 16 T state check qubits. Perform the 16-to-0 identity on the T state check qubits to destructively check them. If they pass, keep the outputs; otherwise discard. Because we consumed the check T states to perform the 16-to-0 factory, instead of having to perform extra T gates to unmaking them, this factory has a rate of 44-to-4, i.e. 11-to-1, which is better than the 15-to-1 we started with!
Hopefully this communicates the idea of how combining factories as subroutines in a larger factory could produce helpful effects. Actually, fun fact, the 15-to-1 factory can be decomposed into two instances of the 8T-to-1CCZ factory. This allows it to be done with a footprint of 4 qubits instead of 5 qubits. So a lot of our "basic" factories can be decomposed into functioning subroutines:

Something I wonder about sometimes is whether all factories, except a few very basic ones, actually decompose into compositions of those basic ones. Or whether there is an infinite hierarchy of atomic factories that cannot be decomposed.
